# Does an inner model always 'know' about smaller inner models?

Tags: set-theory

An inner model of $V$ is some standard transitive model with the same ordinals as $V$. It is obviously a class, so to say it 'exists' means there's some formula for it in $V$.

Suppose we have two inner models $M,N$ such that $M\subsetneq N \subsetneq V$. Is it necessarily true that $N$ 'knows' about $M$? Meaning, **must there be some formula for $M$ within $N$?**

I ask because conceivably, the formula that defined $M$ in $V$ in the first place could have used some parameter not in $N$. So maybe only $V$ 'knows' about $M$, even though it is a subset of $N$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is *no* but the 'obvious' attack vector cannot work: If $M$ is a ground of $V$ (i.e. $V = M[g]$ for some set generic $g$), then $M$ is a ground of any intermediate model $M \subseteq N \subseteq V$ and hence -- by the ground definability lemma --  is definable in $N$ (although this definition may be different from $V$'s definition).

Comment: I'm also pretty certain the answer is 'no', though I'm curious what a counterexample would look like. I thought class forcing is maybe the way to go. Force some new class into there.

Comment: "It is obviously a class, so to say it 'exists' means there's some formula for it in $V$." This seems a bit off to me - when we reason freely about inner models, we generally work in something like NBG/MK, so classes need *not* be definable.

Comment: And now that I think about it, this doesn't seem like a minor point at all. Think about the "set versions" of the questions: (i) Are there set models $M\subsetneq N$ of ZFC with the same ordinals such that $M$ is not definable in $N$? (ii) Are there set models $M_0\subsetneq M_1\subsetneq M_2$ of ZFC with the same ordinals such that $M_0,M_1$ are each definable in $M_2$ but $M_0$ is not definable in $M_1$? These are quite different questions, at least on the face of it.

Comment: So I think the definability assumption you're making is actually quite significant.

Comment: You can produce a counterexample with proper class forcing, as you suggest.

Comment: We can work in the BG model that has the same sets as $V$, and has as classes the definable ones.

Comment: @AlonNavon Well, sure. But which classes do we equip $N$ with to make it into a model of $\mathrm{BG}$? If we again take the $N$-definable classes, we're back to the original question. If we instead take the restrictions of $V$'s classes, the question becomes trivial.

Comment: @StefanMesken We're back to the original question. I just wanted to give Noah a concrete BG model.